# Problem deleting videos using 'Channel Videos' Plug in

Tags: channel-videos

I'm using 'Channel Videos' plug in which works fine to display videos on my sites page. But when I try and delete a video from the entry, it appears to be removed looking at the control panel, I click submit and the video comes back again and still displays on the control panel and on the site. I'm using Channel Videos 3.1.0 and EE 2.5.5

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Have you contacted the developer directly?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've decided to use another plugin now. Thank you

Comment: I am having this issue with 3.2 need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue (also Channel Videos 3.1.0 and EE 2.5.5) on a site which was making use of SSL (https) - I was able to resolve the issue by using https when logged into the CMS. i.e. https://domain.com/system/...

Videos then 'stayed deleted' from the Channel Videos field.

{site_url} = https://domain.com

While I'm not 100% sure why it worked, I hope it helps nonetheless!

Matt

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, in the end I opted for a different solution. But thank you anyway.